# Is there any ruby gem wrapper for p0f?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, networking, tcp, libpcap

This https://github.com/skord/p0f is great. But it is `C`. And does not offer an API. It allows you to do some tricks with the `-Q` option, but still, it's not a lib with API.

Is there any ruby gem that wraps `p0f` as a library and offers an API in order for me to be able to embed it, use it, for instance, in my Rails server?

My long-term goal is to extract TCP level information (such the one that `p0f` gives) from Rails request objects. Any other ideas would be marked as helpful.

Hence, I am looking for an answer on gem existence and any other consultation on how to extract TCP level information equivalent to the information `p0f` gives.

I hope that my question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is such a wrapper, but it shouldn't be too hard to write one using [LibFFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki) to interface the C code. Good luck!